# How to Convert Generic Type (T.Type) to particular type which confirms to any protocol (in this case Codable Protocol)

Tags: json, swift

I wanted to typecast Generic Type ie.. T.Type to type which confirms to Codable protocol and give this as param to other function (which takes only types confirms to Codable Protocol.)

Here is the code which I tried.

I've one generic function which converts JSON data to model objects of Type T as below:

```
extension JSONDecoder {
    static func convertResponse<T: Decodable>(_ response: Data, ofType: T.Type) -> T?  {


        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

        var convertedModel:T?

        do {
            convertedModel = try jsonDecoder.decode(T.self, from: response)
        } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound(let key, let context) {
            print("Json to model conversion error \(key) \(context)")
        } catch DecodingError.valueNotFound(let type, let context) {
            print("Json to model conversion error \(type) \(context)")
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(let type, let context) {
            print("Json to model conversion error \(type) \(context)")
        } catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let context) {
            print("Json to model conversion error \(context)")
        } catch {
            print("There is some other error ")
        }

        return convertedModel
    }
}
```

I've other function which will call above function..this will work fine because it confirms to Codable

```
// When we call this function we need to pass param Type whcih confirms to Codabel protocol.
// However I don't want that way..
func someFunction<T: Codable>(convertTo type: T.Type) {

    let data = Data()

    JSONDecoder.convertResponse(data, ofType: type)
}
```

I wanted to remove Codable conformance in above function as below. However this is giving me compilation error or I may be doing in wrong way

```
func functionWithoutProtocolConform<T>(convertTo type: T.Type) {
    let data = Data() // for eg...

    if type is Decodable.Type {
        let decodableType = type as! Decodable.Type
        JSONDecoder.convertResponse(data, ofType: decodableType) // !!!! Error here
    }
    else {
        // do something else....
    }
}
```

Could you please suggest a way to do this..

Comment: Why not just have two overloads of `someFunction` – one with `T : Decodable`, one unconstrained?

Comment: I need to know if it is not that type that could confirm to protocol do something else..and it would be repetitive code right?..If i have method overloading...